# Ubuntu server 18.04 showing incorrect login after fresh clean install

Tags: server, login

I clean installed ubuntu server on my desktop and it is showing me I correct login even after entering correct credentials. I tried to reinstall the server few other times thinking I typed wrong hanged keyboard. I tried to press the shift key to login to grub.  But that also doesn't work.

While installing it gave me the option to reboot now or exit to shell, I tried to exit to shell, reset password create a new user set their password and that also doesn't work.

I am.not installing anything fancy just default plain ubuntu server on a desktop with us layout English language. All default stuff.

In this process, I have reinstalled ubuntu server 8 to 10 times but the same result over and over again. If anybody has a solution please share or tell me what is the best substitute to ubuntu-server for a small nas file server.

Comment: What do you mean by "incorrect login"? If this is a server version installation, why is the xubuntu tag set? During installation you should have been asked for user name to create and a password for that user, and should be used after boot to create a terminal session (there is no desktop GUI for Ubuntu server).

Comment: Sorry for incorrect tag but it was not allowing me to create new tags and was bot showing relavent tags. By incorrect login i mean it is not accepting the username and password i set during installation

Comment: Please pardon my language iam not a native english speaker. English is a second language for me.